# Weblogic Extended Logging Format Fields - http header authorization

Tags: http, header, authorization, weblogic

I am utilizing Weblogic 12c and looking to add http header 'authorization' to the logs via extended logging format fields.  From what I have found, the following options are available:

date time cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status time-taken

Is there another way to add this functionality?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#autoId12 there is a possibility to create your own custom field by creating java classes to add some ELF field.

Although, I have to say that I wouldn't be able to do so myself.

Comment: I am little perplexed by the w3c standards.  I see references in regards to "cs-username" implementation, yet when I visit http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html; I see no mention of this field. Was this removed from w3c standards?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/w3c-logging), the `cs(Cookie)` keyword shows all the cookies you have in the request, so you do not need to write any code if you would like to show request header info in the Weblogic's `access.log` file.

I have tried it and it works like a charm with `WebLogic Server Version 12.2.1.4.0`.

The value of the `Extended Logging Format Fields` that I use is this: `date time time-taken bytes c-ip s-ip c-dns s-dns sc-status sc-comment cs-username cs-method cs-uri cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query cs(Cookie)`

This config produces the following log:

```
#Version:       1.0
#Fields:        date time time-taken bytes c-ip s-ip c-dns s-dns sc-status sc-comment cs-username cs-method cs-uri cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query cs(Cookie)
#Software:      WebLogic
#Start-Date:    2022-09-15      16:04:30

2022-09-15      16:04:30        2.696   17772   10.178.48.246   weblogic-managed-server-1:7002     10.178.48.246   weblogic-managed-server-1  200     "OK"    -       GET     /myapp/index.xhtml      /myapp/index.xhtml      -       "TST_JSESSIONID=C7BB2m...-HN92Vx!-1879373823; _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_TST_JSESSIONID=kWsB...w7; splunkweb_csrf_token_8000=947...47; my_cookie_consent=...; MYAPP_JSESSIONID=v1o...84"
```